# PyCharm не выводит в консоль

Tags: python, pycharm

Только начал изучать питон, установил PyCharm и столкнулся с проблемой, что не выводит в консоль, если писать в окошке для кода. Зато если писать в консоли , то все ок. Подскажите как это можно исправить.
[image: Вот скрин]

Comment: Откуда у вас `4` в выводе? `print('Hello World')` должен выводить `Hello World`.

Comment: ты вообще тот файл запускаешь?

Comment: То есть если вы сейчас нажмёте зелёный треугольник под "Run:" текст "Hello World" не появится в этом проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте всегда вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И запускайте вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И всегда будете уверены, что запустили то, что хотели

По сути эта идиома (`if __name__ == '__main__':`) отсекает ту часть файла, которая выполняется только при запуске конкретно этого файла. Весь код выше нее будет выполнен в том числе и при импорте из этого файла чего либо.
Но кроме всего прочего у PyCharm для нее есть и вот такая приятная фитча.

Если у Вас PyCharm community, то скорее всего у Вас будут только пункты Run, Debug и Edit

Comment: Можно еще через правый клик внутри редактора -> Run, чтобы не писать if.

Comment: @PavelKarateev, можно, но там целиться в пункт меню дольше. Там меню большое вываливается